# Change number of split

Tags: java

Today, my code works but it makes a split of 2 lines by 2 lines, but that's not the goal.
I want to change the split, i want to divide 50 lines by 50 lines and not 2 by 2.
If I leave like that, I have three files of 2 lines
If i have 135 lines, i want:

- Fist file: 50 lines (line 1-50 of my file) and the file name is 801.
- Second file: 50 lines (line 51-100 of my file) and the file name is 802.
- Third file: 35 lines (line 101-135 of my file) and the file name is 803.

Here, it is my code:

```
private void MyCode(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate, InputStream content, String endpoint, String fileName, HashMap<String, Object> headers){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    long numSplits = 50; //Number of lines per split              
    int sourcesize=0; //Number of lines
    int number = 800; //my filename 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

    try{

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sourcesize++;
            list.add(line); //add the lines in the arraylist
        }

        System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + sourcesize);

        for( int i = 0 ; i <= list.size() ; i+=numSplits) {
            String  Filename = ""+ number;
            System.out.println(Filename);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(list.get(i)).append(System.lineSeparator()).append(list.get(i+1));
            producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(endpoint, builder.toString(), "CamelFileName",Filename); //Used to forward lines and the file name
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I think about:

```
for (int k=0;k<numSplits;k++) {  
      builder.append(list.get(i));
      builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

How to change the split?
How can I cut my `arraylist` all 50 occurrences?

Comment: Please explain your problem, "split of 2 lines by 2 lines" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Sorry @Jaroslaw Pawlak, but I want to adjust my code.
I don't want split my file all 2 lines but every 50 lines.

Comment: I still have no idea what is your problem and what you are trying to do.

Comment: If I have a file of 100 lines, my current code will give me 50 output files.
But if I want my file consists of 100 lines, I want two files and i can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void MyCode(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate, InputStream content, String endpoint, String fileName, HashMap<String, Object> headers){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    int numSplits = 50; 
    int number = 800;          
    int sourcesize=0; 
    try{
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sourcesize++;
            list.add(line); 
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + sourcesize);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parts = cutListInChunksOfSameSize(list, numSplits);

    for (ArrayList<String> part : parts){
         String  Filename = ""+ (number++);
         System.out.println(Filename);
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

         for( int i = 0 ; i <part.size() ;i++){   
             builder.append(part.get(i)).append(System.lineSeparator());                
        }
        producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(endpoint, builder.toString(), "CamelFileName",Filename); 
    }
}

public <T> ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> cutListInChunksOfSameSize(ArrayList<T> list, final int L) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> parts = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
    final int N = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += L) {
      parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + L))));
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I thought of this method but it returns an array, I treat the flat file.

Comment: As far as i can see you are reading the file content into an ArrayList<String> . So you can cut that list into chunks of same size. I will edit my Answer and give you an example

Comment: have tried to keep your logic as it was and make only few changes and add a new method called cutListInChunksOfSameSize which will get an ArrayList as parameter and an integer for the wished size and returns list of ArrayLists. Hope this was what you want.

Comment: Thanks Eritrean!! I tested the method but cutListInChunksOfSameSize method always returns the entire list, for example `cutListInChunksOfSameSize(list, 1)` if I want to split my file my file 50 lines by 50

Comment: I retried your code: 
`[ERROR]: error - class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException occured in ...........: Index: 50, Size: 50 | java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 50, Size: 50`
I have only one file of a single line, I try to understand what's wrong

Comment: i have edited the code twice and not noticed the <= in the inner for loop. change that to "int i = 0 ; i < part.size() ; i++"    I will edit my answer once again. Please check also if you have noticed my last edit at the line 
builder.append(part.get(i)).append(System.lineSeparator());

Comment: Thank you again, it's really great to help me :) !!! Your code works but it returns a file per line, I don't have to be clear it's my fault :(. 
If I have 100 lines, I want two files of 50 lines.

Comment: you only need to modify the for loops. See edited answer.